# how to design a interactive program?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, authentication, interactive

I want to design a interactive login program, here is the workflow:

```
def login(username, password)
    // 1. get login url

    // 2. check captcha
    has_captcha = check_captcha()

    // deal with captcha if necessary
    if has_captcha
       // 3. return captcha to client
       // 4. I should wait until user input the captcha
    end

    // 5. finally, post login
end
```

my problem is at `step 3 and step 4`, my way is:

1. `server` write to captcha to mongodb and wait there.
2. `client` check if mongodb data is updated every 5 seconds
3. `server` will also check mongodb every 5 seconds, if server find mongodb has been updated by client, then get client data from mongodb, continue login.

But this is not that elegant, how do I implement this easily?

Comment: Use RethinkDB instead of Mongo, it has real-time push mechanism out of the box.

Comment: @mudasobwa do I have choice if I do not use any database?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology :: client listens for push and posts to the server.

Comment: @mudasobwa your answer do give me a hint, but can you give me a really simple example? I am not very familiar with this.